# Both box shadow and linear gradient conflict

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am having a problem with creating a linear gradient and box shadow for a button. The problem is gradient works for cross broswers but box shadow does not(inset is not needed). Mainly i needed it for ie8.

My requirement is to write css for a single class(like .submit) with supporting linear gradient and box-shadow for all the browsers.

Comment: So? You need to show us what you have so far. We will not write the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply shadow using this example.

```
.shadow{
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
     zoom: 1;
}
```

you can make your own variations [here](http://css3pie.com/) at css3 pie

Comment: Thankyou very much the link given by you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [shadow filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This would add a shadow on each side of an element:

```
.boxshadow {    
        zoom: 1;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=0, Strength=3)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=45, Strength=2)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=90, Strength=3)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=135, Strength=2)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=180, Strength=3)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=225, Strength=2)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=260, Strength=3)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=305, Strength=2);
}
```

Should work in IE down to Version 6.